# Reverse for 'surveydetails' not found. 'surveydetails' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

I've been stuck on this for a while, can't seem to fix the error.  I've checked the code a hundred times but obviously there is something I'm missing. I have installed my app also.

Can anybody see what I'm missing?

**views.py**

```
 def survey_details(request, id=None):
     context = {}
     surveys = Survey.objects.get(id=id)
     context['survey'] = survey
     return render(request, 'surveydetails.html', context)
```

**feedback.urls.py**

```
path('details/<int:id>', views.survey_details, name="surveydetails"),
```

**surveys.html**

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content%}

    <h1>Surveys</h1>
    <h2>list of {{title}} </h2>
    {% if surveys %}
        <ul>
            {% for survey in surveys %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'feedback:surveydetails' %}">{{ survey.title }}</a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>There are no surveys.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**surveydetails.html**

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content%}

    <h1>Surveys</h1>
    <h2>Detail page</h2>
    <h3>{{question.title}}</h3>
    <p>Details page of {{question.title}}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Show your complete feedback/urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are not passing the survey id.

```
{% for survey in surveys %}
   <li>
     <a href="{% url 'feedback:surveydetails' survey.id %}">{{ survey.title }}</a>
 </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's right, thank you very much. I accept your answer.